Java Email sender unable to send emails
I am trying to configure an email sender in java. I have a google account that I have configured the SMTP server and I created an app password for the account.
I then added the following configuration into my application.yml :
mail:
host: smtp.gmail.com
port: 587
username: MY_EMAIL
password: MY_PASSWORD
properties:
  mail:
    smtp:
      trust: "*"
    auth: true
    starttls:
      enabled: true
      required: true
    connectiontimeout: 5000
    timeout: 3000
    writetimeout: 5000

This is my email sender class:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EmailService {

@Value("${spring.mail.username}")
private String mailOrigin;

private final JavaMailSender mailSender;
private final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

@Async
public void sendEmail(String to, String userName, EmailTemplateName emailTemplate, String confirmationUrl, String activationCode, String subject) throws MessagingException{
    String templateName;
    if(emailTemplate == null){
        templateName = "confirm-email";
    }else{
        templateName = emailTemplate.getName();
    }
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("username", userName);
    properties.put("confirmationUrl", confirmationUrl);
    properties.put("activation_code", activationCode);

    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariables(properties);
    helper.setFrom(mailOrigin);
    helper.setTo(to);
    helper.setSubject(subject);
    String template = templateEngine.process(templateName, context);
    helper.setText(template, true);
    mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
  }
 }

However, I still get the following exception when trying to send emails:
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: 
org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS 
 command first. For more information, go to
530-5.7.0  https://support.google.com/a/answer/3221692 and review RFC 3207
530 5.7.0 specifications. 5b1f17b1804b1-432da24498csm101062995e9.1 - gsmtp

What am I doing wrong here? From my understanding the JavaMailSender should already configure the session based on my inputs on the application.yml right?

hint: Must issue a STARTTLS command first so ensure  the client you are using supports TLS

@MarcinOrlowski, I have set up an app in gmail following the 2 factor authentication. How can I check if this is configured to use TLS? I am using java 17 which by default support TLS 1.3

Was able to solve the issue. Actually was just an indentation issue on my application.yml.
The starttls should be inside the smtp like this:
    mail:
     smtp:
       trust: "*"
       auth: true
       starttls:
         enabled: true
         required: true
     connectiontimeout: 5000
     timeout: 3000
     writetimeout: 5000

